# Malfunctioning USB3.0 after sometime of usage

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, external-hard-drive

My system is a desktop Windows8.1. I have two USB 3.0 external drives. One is a 1TB Wester Digital and the other is 2TB Transcend. I need to transfer some files from the 1TB HDD to the another. So I plugged both drives at the two rear USB3.0 slots and started copying. I forgot the total size of the files, but the transfer last for two hours. After I copied, I verified if it is indeed successful by playing one of the file on the 2TB HDD. After confirming, I eject both drives and remove.

Today, I need to continue copying another batches of files from and to the same set of drives. The problem is now the two USB3.0 slots are not functioning. I tried using those slots for my keyboard and mouse, but the same as the external drives, it seems that the device is "powered", (hence the LED) but not detected by my computer.

**I've tried to fix this by restarting with the two drives plugged and unplugged, but the problem still persists**. This is how the device manager now looks like:

[image]

I now continue copying the second batch of files using my two front USB2.0 ports, and yeah, the speed is compromised. There are no smoke or burnt smell and the other USB2.0 parts are functional. What can I do to fixed these USB ports?

Comment: Did your restart your computer (should always be the 1st troubleshooting step)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I did, see my edit.